# CardAction DisplayText doesn't seem to work

Tags: botframework

When I create (v4 sdk) a postBack CardAction with Title, DisplayText and a Value I expect the value to be posted back, the Title to be shown in a button and the DisplayText to be shown in the trail. What I typically get is either nothing the display trail (if the value isn't a string) or the value if it is a string. Have I misread how this is supposed to work? PS, mostly testing in the emulator.

Comment: What channel and language are you using?

Comment: emulator (directline) or webchat

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, every channel can have different behavior when it comes buttons. As a general best practice I will fill in all the string parameters with the same value to cover the differences across channels. You can see an example of this in [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/a19da027f28b9dc74fa127aa505a2fb7726e67f6/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/GraphAuthenticationBot.cs#L148)

right now it sounds like you have this:

```
new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Help", displayText: "Help", value: "Help")
```

Try adding the `text` parameter like this:

```
new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Help", text:"Help", displayText: "Help", value: "Help")
```

Comment: That doesn't effect it. The docs explicitly state the the option 'displayText' should be shown in the trail, but it seems to be completely ignored in the emulator and also the webchat.  Also the displayed text in the trail seems to follow the 'value' which IMO is the least useful. Surly the value is for understanding the choice in the Bot, not for consumption by the user?

Comment: I would argue that value is most useful.  For example if you had actionType.OpenUrl the value would be the url to open.  I totally missed in my answer that you are using postBack which is intended to be used if you are not trying to display a message from the user to the bot when the button is clicked.  If you would like the message to display, use the actionType.ImBack actionType.  This will display the message.

Comment: I don't follow your logic re: value. The point of Display Text is to display the text. Value is an indicator of the underlying value you wish the bot to process. Given that display text is optional, then yes I would say show the value. But when it's used...it should be used.

Comment: One could also interpret "display text" as the text that will be displayed on the button itself, which has always been my interpretation. Can you please link the doc you were using? Good chance it is just wrong.  If you wanted you could also [file a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).  If you want the bot to silently respond to a button click, use `postback`, if you would like the text to be displayed in the conversation use `ImBack`.

Comment: Sure, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions'displayText  Optional. Echoed by the user into the chat stream when the action is performed. This text is not sent to your bot.' Where is the room for interpretation?