# MsTeam herocard ActionTypes.ImBack behaving differently

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have created herocard with ActionTypes.ImBack

while I am using webchat & facebook onclick on button it displaying card.title in chat windows

**e.g. Show me menu"**

But in team it displaying card.valus that I do not wan to show to end user

**e.g. "Action:IntentName"**

I have try **postback, messageback & invoke** in MsTeams but both not working at all

```
plButton1 = new CardAction()
{
Value ="Action:IntentName",
Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
Title = "Show me menu"
};
```

Expected output : "Show me menu"

Actual output : "Action:IntentName"

Comment: Why not just put "Show me menu" as the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Text doesn't echo back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626960/display-text-doesnt-echo-back)

Comment: I need to keep button value different from Intent name and display text. on click on button want to start indent directly without going to NLP and this I wan to do dynamically based on my configuration so I can't hard code

Comment: My answer to the question I linked explains everything you need to know. Please read it thoroughly and let me know if you still need help.

Comment: I have issue with MsTeam messageBack, Postback & invoke not working
if I am using imback it showing button value that I do not wan to show
I need to do different functional for button click and message type so I am keeping different value for button and based on value proceeding further

Comment: Are you using v3 or v4?

Comment: If all you're doing is taking action based on which button was clicked, why do you need hidden metadata? Why not just operate based on the activity's text that gets displayed in the conversation history?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

### Important information from the answer I linked

> **Card behavior is channel-specific by nature.**
>
> This is true across the board, regardless of card type, action type, or channel. While certain guidelines apply to, say, the properties of card actions, you really can't depend on a property like `displayText` behaving the way you expect it to. You need to test the card yourself. Here's some code that will help you test a variety of card action types and properties:

```
var actionTypes = new List<string>
{
    ActionTypes.ImBack,
    ActionTypes.PostBack,
    ActionTypes.MessageBack,
};

var cardActions = actionTypes.Select(actionType => new CardAction(
    actionType,
    $"{actionType} title",
    null,
    $"{actionType} value",
    $"{actionType} text",
    $"{actionType} displayText"
)).ToList();

var reply = activity.CreateReply("Reply:");

reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { new Attachment(HeroCard.ContentType, content: new HeroCard("Hero title", "Hero subtitle", "Hero text", buttons: cardActions)) };
reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions(new List<string> { activity.From.Id }, cardActions);

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

> These three action types (ImBack, PostBack, and MessageBack) have some expected behavior associated with them:
>
> - ImBack is meant to display a message in the conversation history as though the user typed it
> - PostBack is meant to send an invisible message to the bot with hidden metadata
> - MessageBack is meant to send a message to the bot that gets displayed in the conversation history *and* contains hidden metadata, combining the other two types
>
> Again, you cannot count on this behavior to be implemented consistently across different channels.

### Additional information relevant to your question specifically

If you experiment with that C# code, you can determine that Microsoft Teams treats card actions like this:

- **ImBack** uses `title` as the button label and uses `value` as the activity's text and the rendered message.
- **PostBack** and **MessageBack** use `title` as the button label, `text` as the activity's text, and `displayText` as the rendered message.

What this means is that if you want to have a hero card in Teams send a message containing data not shown to the user, you need to use **PostBack** or **MessageBack**. You'll want to create the card differently depending on what channel the bot is communicating on. You can determine the channel from the activity's `ChannelId` property:

```
switch (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId)
{
    case Channels.Msteams:
        action = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
            Title = "Show me menu",
            Text = "Action:IntentName",
            DisplayText = "Show me menu",
        };

        break;
    default:
        action = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
            Title = "Show me menu",
            Value = "Action:IntentName",
        };

        break;
}
```

Lucky for you, in all three of your channels the information you want to received from the button will be in the activity's `Text` property, so you won't need another switch statement when responding to the activity generated by a card action:

```
var result = turnContext.Activity.Text;
```